# How to set Unity3D vertical camera rotation limit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, c#-4.0

I want to rotate my camera horizontally around the object 360 degree and want to limit my vertical rotation from -45 to 45 degrees. I have found some solution over internet but none of them are work for mouse click input. Here is my working code without vertical rotation limit.

```
[SerializeField]
private Camera _camera;

[SerializeField]
private Transform target;

private Vector3 previousPosition;



// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        previousPosition = _camera.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Vector3 direction = previousPosition - _camera.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        _camera.transform.position = target.position;

        _camera.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(1, 0, 0), direction.y * 180);
        _camera.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), -direction.x * 180, Space.World);
        _camera.transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, 0.3f, -3));

        previousPosition = _camera.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);


    }

}
```

If someone can point me how can I limit the vertical rotation that would be very helpful for me.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make limited camera movement in Unity C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271578/how-to-make-limited-camera-movement-in-unity-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's be honest, the `Rotate` command is a relative method and works to limit inefficiencies. To solve the problem of limiting the camera, you must have fixed and controllable variables. Attach the code below to the camera, which solves the constraint problem, but keep in mind that the camera is limited in its local angles. To determine the angle and direction of the camera, child empty it and rotate empty in the main direction put,

```cs
public float LimitAngleX = 45;
public float LimitAngleY = 180;

private float AngleX;
private float AngleY;

public float sensitivity = 10f;
public void Update()
{
    var angles = transform.localEulerAngles;

    var xAxis = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * Time.unscaledDeltaTime * sensitivity;
    var yAxis = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * Time.unscaledDeltaTime * sensitivity;

    AngleX = Mathf.Clamp (AngleX-yAxis, -LimitAngleX, LimitAngleX);
    AngleY = Mathf.Clamp (AngleY+xAxis, -LimitAngleY, LimitAngleY);

    angles.x = AngleX;
    angles.y = AngleY;

    var euler = Quaternion.Euler (angles);
    
    transform.localRotation = euler;

    transform.localEulerAngles = angles;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

they way u codded that camera rotation system is great, but it might have some problems , i highly recommend following a guy called [Brakeys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QajrabyTJc) on youtube that made a perfect moving and rotating systems .
anyway u can use a method called `Mathf.Clamp` to set the minimal and maximum numbers of a float without exceeding those limits .
this is an example that isn't going to work but rather demonstration.
`float cameraLimits = Mathf.Clamp(MouseY, 20 ,90);`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion, I will look into that channel. I have tried  Mathf.Clamp but cant make it work

Comment: ```float cameraLimits = Mathf.Clamp(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"), 20 ,90);``` and
you can make the correct is green, this means that this question has been answered (I mean the picture correctly) under the title answer

Comment: you can change those numbers: Mathf.Clamp(MouseY, 100 80);