# how can I prevent the camera from sliding after it rotates around the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, orthographic

I am new to game developing, and I am building a game with an orthographic camera,
the camera suppose to be following the player and when I click and drag the mouse it supposes to turn around him.

I managed to make the camera turn around the player, but when I add the code for the mouse drag when I hold the mouse it turns but when I release it slides.

This is my C# code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerFollow : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform PlayerTransform;

    private Vector3 _cameraOffset;

    [Range(0.01f, 1.0f)]
    [SerializeField] float SmoothFactor = 0.5f;

    [SerializeField] bool LookAtPlayer = false;

    [SerializeField] bool RotateAroundPlayer = true;

    [SerializeField] float RotationsSpeed = 5.0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        _cameraOffset = transform.position - PlayerTransform.position;  
    }
   
    void LateUpdate () {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {

            RotateAroundPlayer = true;

        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            RotateAroundPlayer = false;

        }

        if (RotateAroundPlayer)
        {
            Quaternion camTurnAngle =
                Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * RotationsSpeed, Vector3.up);

            _cameraOffset = camTurnAngle * _cameraOffset;
        }
        Vector3 newPos = PlayerTransform.position + _cameraOffset;

        transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, newPos, SmoothFactor);


        if (LookAtPlayer || RotateAroundPlayer)
            transform.LookAt(PlayerTransform);
    }
}
```

Comment: After I fixed the indentation of the code in your question, I realized that you might put the right brace on a wrong place by mistake.

Comment: Thank you but, no it is on the right position, it was not just organized

Comment: Then have you selected LookAtPlayer in the inspector?

Comment: It did not work before, but now it was fixed with the look at, thank you, can you suggest me how to rotate the camera angle up and down?

Comment: Try to change Vector3.up to Vector3.right.

Comment: Thank you this helped I just have one other thing, how can I set a limit for the up and down angle I tried  ` _cameraOffset.y = Mathf.Clamp(_cameraOffset.y, maxViewingAngle, minViewingAngle);` but it did not work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72516784/how-to-set-unity3d-vertical-camera-rotation-limit

Comment: Thank you, but this did not work for me